# Generics - Cannot add to a List with unbounded wildcard

Tags: java, generics

I instantiate the following list:

```
// I am just revising generics again and the following is just cursory code!
List<? super Integer> someList = new ArrayList<Object>();
someList.add(new Object());
```

The above will not work. I get a compiler error. However, the following works:

```
List<? super Integer> someList = new ArrayList<Object>();
someList.add(11);
```

I am aware that you can add objects to a collection which contains an **unbounded** wildcard, not a bounded wildcard.

However, why does the above not work?
An Object is a supertype of an Integer, so why can't I add it?

Comment: minor term issue: `List<? super Integer>` is lower bounded wildcard; `List<?>` is unbounded wildcard. Even though you use unbounded wildcard `List<?>`, you can't add instance of any type; you can only add `null`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That declares that it's a list of something that's a supertype of Integer, not that the list can contain anything that's a supertype of Integer. In other words, to the compiler, it could be a `List<Integer>`, a `List<Number>` or a `List<Object>`, but it doesn't know which, so you can't add just anything to the List. The only thing you can safely add is an Integer, since that's guaranteed to be a subtype of any type the List could potentially hold.

In other words, the `?` represents *one* type, not *any* type. It's a non-obvious but important distinction.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your first sentence. So, it can't be a list of Objects *and* Integers. Just one single type? But I am able to add an Integer to the list - in response to the very last part of your answer.

Comment: Oh right. My bad. Since Integer is the boundary and is guaranteed to be a subtype of any type that the List could be, then Integer can be added. No other type can be, though, such as Number, even though it's a supertype of Integer. As for my first sentence, I think you've got it right: a generic wildcard doesn't mean the list can contain objects of multiple types. It means the list contains objects of an unknown type. Since that type *could* be Number, for example, it's illegal to add Objects to the list.

Comment: Updated my answer in accordance with these comments.

Comment: Then why this is not accepting someList.add(integerValue) if it become List<? extends Number> someList? It could determine the type as Number from the upper bound.

Answer (score 4):

For the variable `someList`, all the compiler/language has to work with is the static type `List<? super Integer>`. It's possible that it could have been assigned from a `List<Integer>`. Obviously, you don't want to add a `new Object()` to `List<Integer>`.

You can add `null` to `List<? super Integer>`, and you can pass the list to another method that captures the generic type and can therefore move references around the list (method such as, `Collections.shuffle`).

Comment: I find this odd though. Should you not be allowed to add an Object anyway as it's within the same inheritance hierarchy as an Integer? Or is this more of a subjective assumption - why add an Object to a "list of Integers"?

Comment: The problem is that if you have `List<? super Integer> list = new List<Integer>()`, you shouldn't be able to add an `Object` to a list that's actually a `List<Integer>`.  It's perfectly objective.

Comment: But I don't have a List<? super Integer> list = new List<Integer>(). I have List<? super Integer> list = new ArrayList<Object>()

Comment: @Joeblackdev Java is a statically-typed language. What you can do to an object is determined by its static type (though the behaviour may be dynamic).

Answer (score 2):

A `List<? super Integer>` is not a list which contains any elements of any supertype of `Integer` (which also makes no sense), but a list a concrete unknown element type which is a supertype of `Integer`. So the compiler has no chance to determine, if the element to be added is of the right concrete type.

Any Collections with wildcards in the element type are per se not extendable, but they are modifiable (you may remove an element or clear the whole list).

Answer (score 2):

When the compiler hits `someList.add(new Object())`, it doesn't remember how you instantiate `someList`. All information the compiler has is how `someList` is declared, i.e `List<? super Integer> someList`. Since you may instantiate `someList` by either

```
someList = new ArrayList<Object>()
```

or

```
someList = new ArrayList<Integer>()
```

and the compiler doesn't know which one it is, hence the compiler doesn't allow you to do `someList.add(new Object())` because `someList` might be a `List<Integer>`.