# Capturing wildcards in Java generics

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, inference

From [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html) Oracle Java tutorial:

> The WildcardError example produces a capture error when compiled:

```
public class WildcardError {

    void foo(List<?> i) {
        i.set(0, i.get(0));
    }
}
```

After this error demonstration, they fix the problem by using a helper method:

```
public class WildcardFixed {
    void foo(List<?> i) {
        fooHelper(i);
    }

    // Helper method created so that the wildcard can be captured
    // through type inference.
    private <T> void fooHelper(List<T> l) {
        l.set(0, l.get(0));
    }
}
```

First, they say that the list input parameter (`i`) is seen as an `Object`:

> In this example, the compiler processes the `i` input parameter as being
>   of type Object.

Why then `i.get(0)` does not return an `Object`? if it was already passed in as such?

Furthermore what is the point of using a `<?>` when then you have to use an helper method using `<T>`. Would not be better using directly `T` which can be inferred?

Comment: This is what Eclipse gives me: `The method set(int, capture#1-of ?) in the type List<capture#1-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (int, capture#2-of ?)` Sounds even more ridiculous.

Comment: I just wrote an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30797805/understanding-a-captured-type-in-java/30798066#30798066) which explains wildcard capture for another question. That information seems relevant for this question also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`List<?>` does mean list of object of unknown type, it's not the same as `List<Object>`.

Because we don't know the type of elements in the list result of `i.get(0)` is considered by Java as `Object`, and you cannot add `Object` to `List<?>`. In case as your Java could be smarter, but in more complex code with `<?>` wildcards it's easy to make it no type safe.

Comment: As far as I remember such case is explained with details in "Effective Java" by Joshua Bloch

Comment: **List<?>** is equivalent to **List<? extends Object>**