# Understanding a captured type in Java (symbol '?')

Tags: java, generics

What is `?`. Is it related to implementation details of the Java compiler or the type is defined in the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html).

For instance,

```
public interface RecipientTypeVisitor<ReturnType> {
    public ReturnType visit(RecipientSetType t);
}

public class RecipientSetType extends RecipientType{

    public Integer accept(RecipientTypeVisitor<?> visitor){ //Error:
        return visitor.visit(this);             //Cannot convert capture of #1 to Integer
    }
}
```

But if we write this:

```
public interface RecipientTypeVisitor<ReturnType> {
    public ReturnType visit(RecipientSetType t);
}

public class RecipientSetType extends RecipientType{

    public Object accept(RecipientTypeVisitor<?> visitor){ //Ok:
        return visitor.visit(this);             //this implies tha the capture of #1 is 
                                     //a subtype of Object as any refrence type in Java.
    }
}
```

That's all I can say about a `captured type`. So what is it actually?

Comment: What exactly do you want to know about this object? like it's class name? or something else?

Comment: Are you wondering why your first example doesn't compile? `visitor.visit()` returns a `ReturnType` which can´t be returned as an `Integer` but as an `Object`.

Comment: in RecipientTypeVisitor<?> the '?' is a wild card you dont know its type. how you can assume its Integer ? so for compiler its Object

Comment: @Aakash I want to know exactly what I asked about. Is that type (and its properties) defined in the JLS or it's just an implementation's internals for the [captuerd convetion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10) sakes.

Comment: It would be either `ReturnType` or one of it's child classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The capture of a wildcard type is a type that is used by the compiler represent the type of a specific instance of the wildcard type, in one specific place.

Example: Take for example a method with two wildcard parameters, `void m(Ex<?> e1, Ex<?> e2)`. The declared types of `e1` and `e2` are written exactly the same, `Ex<?>`. But `e1` and `e2` could have different and incompatible runtime types.

The type checker must not consider the types equal even if they are written the same way. Therefore, during compilation the type parameters of `e1` and `e2` are given specific types, new ones for each place they are used. These new types are called the *capture* of their declared types.

The capture of a wildcard is an unknown, but normal and concrete type. It can be used the same way as other types.

A technical description of this can be found in the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10):

> 5.1.10. Capture Conversion
>
> Let G name a generic type declaration (§8.1.2, §9.1.2) with n type parameters A1,...,An with corresponding bounds U1,...,Un.
>
> There exists a capture conversion from a parameterized type G (§4.5) to a parameterized type G, where, for 1 ≤ i ≤ n :
>
> - If Ti is a wildcard type argument (§4.5.1) of the form ?, then Si is a fresh type variable whose upper bound is Ui[A1:=S1,...,An:=Sn] and whose lower bound is the null type (§4.1).
> - ...

We can apply this to your example:

```
public Integer accept(RecipientTypeVisitor<?> visitor){ //Error:
    return visitor.visit(this);             //Cannot convert capture of #1 to Integer
}
```

A capture of the type parameter of `RecipientTypeVisitor` is introduced during compilation. The captured type parameter is concrete but totally unknown (the JLS calls this a "fresh type variable"), and certainly not convertible to `Integer`.

There is no way to denote the capture of a wildcard type directly, so you can't declare variables of that type or do much with it. You can however get a name for it indirectly by calling a generic method with it as a parameter. The JLS section I cited has a nice example of this further down:

> ```
> public static void reverse(List<?> list) { rev(list); }
> private static <T> void rev(List<T> list) {
>     List<T> tmp = new ArrayList<T>(list);
>     for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
>         list.set(i, tmp.get(list.size() - i - 1));
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: The example above can also be found in *Wildcard Capture* topic of **Java Generics and Collections by Maurice Naftalin & Philip Wadler** book. Type variable **T** has captured the **Wildcard**

Answer (score 3):

You have some choices :

1. you have to replace ? by Integer in the signature of accept method.
2. you could parametrize your method accept too :

`public <T> T accept(RecipientTypeVisitor<T> visitor) {...}`

this  indicates your method uses some generics and links some of its components.

Answer (score 1):

Every class extends from Object so the typecast from `?` to `Object` is safe.
To get the same with `Integer` you can use `RecipientTypeVisitor<? extends Integer>` but since Integer is a final class that is useless, `Integer` cannot be subclassed. It is equivalent to `RecipientTypeVisitor<Integer>`.

Why do you want this?

You can check the [official tutorial here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html).

The most important thing to know:

> In generic code, the question mark (?), called the wildcard,
>   represents an unknown type.
>
> (...)
>
> In some cases, the compiler infers the type of a wildcard. For
>   example, a list may be defined as List but, when evaluating an
>   expression, the compiler infers a particular type from the code. This
>   scenario is known as wildcard capture.
>
> For the most part, you don't need to worry about wildcard capture,
>   except when you see an error message that contains the phrase "capture
>   of".

Answer (score 1):

The char `?` is a wildcard meaning you don't know the type. its doesn't mean its type is `Object` its by definition `undefined` but in Java you can hold any type of object in `Object` type.

```
ArrayList<?> list1 = new Arraylist<?>(); // list of undefined objects
```

You cannot add objects in list1, but after casting you can.

```
ArrayList<Object> list2 = new Arraylist<Object>(); // list of objects of type Object
```

You can add objects in list2 of any type

Answer (score 1):

(This is from another answer of mine, but it is more suitable for this question, explaning wildcard itself)

A wildcard `?` is **not a type**. It is a *type argument*. The syntax though is very deceiving (by design).

Let's use a different syntax - if there's any 1st-level wildcard, use `{}` instead of `<>`, e.g.

```
List{?},  Map{String, ? extends Number}
```

The meaning of `{?}` is to declare a union type

```
List{? extends Number}  ==  union of List<Number>, List<Integer>, List<Long>, ....
```

It's easy to see that, `List<Integer>` is a subtype of  `List{? extends Number}`; and 
 `List{? extends Number}` is a subtype of `List{? extends Object}`

In our syntax, `<>` is reserved for substituting type vars with **types**. So we write 
`List<String>`, etc. It's easy to understand their meaning - just replace `T`'s with `String` in the source code of `List`, we get a  good-old plain class.

```
    interface List<String>
        String get(int)
```

This cannot be done for wildcard - it makes no sense

```
    interface List<?>
        ? get(int)
```

So it is not allowed to `new ArrayList{?}()`, or `class MyList implements List{?}`

So, how can we use `List{?}`? What methods we can call on it?

When the type of an *expression* is a `List{?}`, we know that it is an object, and the object must belong to a subclass of `List<x>` for some unknown **type** `x`. This is *wildcard capture*

```
obj is a List{?}  =>  obj is a List<x>, where x a subtype of Object.
```

Even though the exact type of `x` is unknown at compile time, we can still do the substitution

```
    interface List<x>
        x get(int)
```

so we can make sense of the call `obj.get(0)`; it returns `x`, and `x` is a subtype of `Object`; so we can assign the return value to an `Object`.