# Why does Java ArrayList's reverse method doesn't use capture of wildcard?

Tags: java, generics, types, collections

I'm currently studying on Effective Java Item 26, 27.

I learned about the captured type and looked up on Java Collections's reverse method,

and recognized that Java developers didn't use capture of type.

Looked up on GPT, and is replies that Java Developers might not have used it

because using type capture would increase the complexity of the code.

I kind of get the idea, but wonder this is the actual idea.

[Understanding a captured type in Java (symbol '?')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30797805/understanding-a-captured-type-in-java-symbol#answer-30798066)

[Chapter 5. Conversions and Contexts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10)

```java
private static <T> void swapHelper(List<T> list, int i, int j) {    // captured!
        T temp = list.get(i);
        list.set(i, list.get(j));
        list.set(j, temp);
}
```

I know the method above (swapHelper) can be used. Just curious why they didn't used it.

Comment: You can see with [`Collections::swap`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/20e94784c9f7c30e95550c72aedb5e986a153114/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java#L520) that using `List<?>` requires raw types and suppressing warnings. Given a swap method inherently needs to both read and _write_ to the list, I never understood why the built-in `swap` method _did not_ use `List<T>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer -- generics are powerful and useful, but not every method needs them.

Think about it. You want to reverse a list. Not take something out, or put something back in. What would generics give you here?

If you wanted to extract something from the list, generics would allow you to maintain type-safety by ensuring that what comes out is of a particular type.

If you wanted to put something into the list, generics would allow you to ensure that the item you are inserting into the list is a type that the list can handle.

But in your situation, your items are already in the list, and you are not taking them out right at this moment. Specifically, the method's return type is void. Therefore, what do generics give you?

The answer is - nothing useful. At least not for this shuffle method. Like I said, they are useful elsewhere, but not for this shuffle method.

And you will see similar things for other methods. Consider the following.

- [`Collections.disjoint(Collection<?> c1, Collection<?> c2) --> boolean`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#disjoint(java.util.Collection,java.util.Collection))
- [`Collections.frequency(Collection<?> c1, Object o) --> int`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#frequency(java.util.Collection,java.lang.Object))

For both of the above examples, they don't actually care about what the parameterized type is for each of the `Collection` parameters. So, they simply put those aside, and focus on doing the actual task given. Also notice that their return types are unrelated to the parameterized types of each `Collection`, so again, there is no benefit to be had by inserting a type parameter here.

Use generics where they are useful. They add complexity, so the only time you should include them is when the tradeoff actually gives you something good in exchange.

Comment: I was curious about the usage of the capture of wildcard, but your comment also helped me understand more about the generics, especially 'don't use generics always!'. Thnx :)

Comment: Anytime. Be sure to accept the answer that solves your problem. And upvote any answers that are helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The wildcard symbol '?', can add complexity to the code in certain situations, while the `swapHelper` method it might not be necessary or advantageous in many common scenarios.
In many cases, when you're working with generics and collections, you already know the type of elements you're dealing with so there's no need to use a captured type and by doing this you make the code more straightforward and less error-prone.

Captured types typically come into play when you're dealing with unknown or mixed types within a collection. However, in practice, we often try to structure the code in a way that avoids such situations to keep the codebase more manageable and comprehensible.