# Difference between Bounded Type parameter (T extends) and Upper Bound Wildcard (? extends)

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard, bounded-types

I know that there was a similar question already posted, although I think mine is somewhat different...

Suppose you have two methods:

```
// Bounded type parameter
private static <T extends Number> void processList(List<T> someList) {

}

// Upper bound wildcard
private static void processList2(List<? extends Number> someList) {
    // ...
}
```

As far as I know, both methods accepts arguments, that are `List` of type `Number` or `List` of *subtype* of `Number`.

But what's the difference between the two methods after all?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are several differences between the two syntaxes during compile time :

- With the first syntax, you can add elements to `someList` but with the second, you can't. This is commonly known as [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super) and less commonly known as the PUT and GET prinicple.
- With the first syntax, you have a handle to the type parameter `T` so you can use it to do things such as define local variables within the method of type `T`, cast a reference to the type `T`, call methods that are available in the class represented by `T`, etc. But with the second syntax, you don't have a handle to the type so you can't do any of this.
- The first method can actually be called from the second method to
  capture the wildcard. This is the most common way to [capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043874/java-generics-wildcard-capture-misunderstanding) a
  wildcard via a helper method.

  ```
  private static <T extends Number> void processList(List<T> someList) {
      T n = someList.get(0);
      someList.add(1,n); //addition allowed.   
  }

  private static void processList2(List<? extends Number> someList) {
      Number n = someList.get(0);
      //someList.add(1,n);//Compilation error. Addition not allowed.
      processList(someList);//Helper method for capturing the wildcard
  }
  ```

Note that since generics are compile time sugar, these differences at a broader level are only limited to the compilation.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of the below differences :

a) Modifying your list inside the method, consider the below code :

```java
    // Bounded type parameter
    private static <T extends Number> void processList(List<T> someList)
    {

       
       T t = someList.get(0);
       if ( t.getClass() == Integer.class )
       {
           Integer myNum = new Integer(4);
           someList.add((T) myNum);
       }
       
    }

    // Upper bound wildcard
    private static void processList2(List<? extends Number> someList)
    {
        Object o = someList.get(0);
        if ( o instanceof Integer )
        {
            Integer myNum = new Integer(4);
            someList.add(myNum); // Compile time error !!
        }
    }
```

With wildcard, you cannot add elements to the list! The compiler tells you that it doesn't know what is `myNum`. But in the first method, you could add an `Integer` by first checking if `T` is `Integer`, with no compile time error.

b) The first method is called generic method. It follows the syntax that is defined for a [generic method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html).
The upper bounds specified in the method definition are used to **restrict** the parameter types.

The second one is NOT necessarily called a generic method, it is a normal method that happens to accept a generic *parameter*.
The wildcard `?` with `extends` keyword is used as a means of **relaxing** the types that the method can accept.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is on the compiler side.
On the first one you can use the type (to cast something or use it as a bound to call another method for example) while on the second one, you cannot use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the type information then go with bounded.  With the wildcard, the argument will appear as a generic Object and you won't be able to call methods based on that type.

```
public static <T extends Object> ListIterator<T> createListIterator(ListIterator<T> o)
{
    return new ListIteratorAdaptor<T>(o);
}
```

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html

Answer (score -1):

There are following three types of Wildcard usually used with Generic in JAVA. Each one is explained as below with example.

***Upper-bounded Wildcard:***

*? extends T* : In Upper bounded wildcard only T or its subtypes will be supported.
For example we have an Animal class and have Dog , Cat as its subtypes. So following generic methods will only
accept parameters of type `Data<Animal>, Data<Dog> and Data<Cat>`

```
public static void add(Data<? extends Animal> animalData) {

}
```

***Lower-bounded Wildcard:***

*? super T* : In Lower-bounded wildcard only T or its super types will be supported.
Same example we used for defining Lower-bounded Wildcard. Lets say we have Animal class as super or parent class
and Dog as its child class. Now below method use Lower-bounded Wildcard and will only accept parameters of type

```
Data<Animal>, Data<Dog> and  Data<Object>

public static void add(Data<? super Dog> animalData) {
}
```

***Unbounded Wildcard:***

*? :* Unbounded wildcard supports all types. So our above example method can take parameters of type

```
Data<Animal>, Data<Dog> , Data<Object> and Data<Cat>
public static void add(Data<?> animalData) {       
}
```

Comment: Is was a polite feedback. I recommend taking feedback with the intention to improve and not with prejudgment.