# Java method signature compatibility

Tags: java, methods, signature, method-signature

I have this sample code showing different method signatures:

```
public class Main {
    public static interface MyMap extends Map {}
    public void func1(List<MyMap> m) {}
    public void func2(List<Map> m) {}
    public void func3(List<? extends Map> m) {}
    public void func4(List<? extends Map<?, ?>> m) {}
    public <M extends Map<?, ?>> void func5(List<M> m) {}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<MyMap> myMap = null;
        Main main = new Main();
        main.func1(myMap); // OK
        main.func2(myMap); // not applicable
        main.func3(myMap); // OK
        main.func4(myMap); // not applicable
        main.func5(myMap); // OK
    }
}
```

When I have `MyMap` extending the raw type `Map` I have these confusions about method signature compatibility in Java.

As seen `func1` is a control test, obviously IDE will not complain. In `func2`, I can understand `MyMap` is not exactly a `Map`, hence IDE is complaining. After updating the signature like `func3` it works again. As for `func4`, I sort of thinking `Map<?,?>` is not the same as a raw type `Map`, thats why IDE is complaining again? But then what puzzles me most is `func5` because it looks equivalent to `func4` but IDE is not complaining?

Answer (score 0):

I think this was answered already:

[Difference between Bounded Type parameter and Upper Bound Wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38944896/difference-between-bounded-type-parameter-and-upper-bound-wildcard)

Only exception, you added Raw Type Eresure, but I don't think it somehow influence the result.

Also, I thinks you may find next useful:

```
main.func4((List<? extends Map<?, ?>>) myMap); // OK, but unchecked warning
```