# Java generics: Wildcard capture compilation error

Tags: java, templates, generics, compiler-errors

**I get following compilation errors:**

```
The method sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (T[], Comparator<capture#1-of ? extends T>) Main.java   /Sorting/src/com/kash/test  line 11
The method sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (T[], Comparator<capture#2-of ? super T>)   Main.java   /Sorting/src/com/kash/test  line 15
The method sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (T[], Comparator<T>)    Main.java   /Sorting/src/com/kash/test  line 19
```

**when I compile (with JDK 1.7.0 in Eclipse Juno) this code:**

```
package com.kash.test;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

// 3 attempts to write a wrapper over: Collections' method
//      public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)
public class Main {

    public static <T> void sort1(T[] array, Comparator<? extends T> c) {
        Collections.sort(array, c); // line 11
    }

    public static <T> void sort2(T[] array, Comparator<? super T> c) {
        Collections.sort(array, c); // line 15
    }

    public static <T> void sort3(T[] array, Comparator<T> c) {
        Collections.sort(array, c); // line 19
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

I have read following but did not really understand much. Any help?

- [Java Generics: Wildcard capture misunderstanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043874/java-generics-wildcard-capture-misunderstanding)
- [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs/2723538)
- More reading from thread above:

  - [Can't add value to the Java collection with wildcard generic type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716920/cant-add-value-to-the-java-collection-with-wildcard-generic-type)
  - [Java Collections using wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69702/java-collections-using-wildcard)
  - [Generic collection & wildcard in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363170/generic-collection-wildcard-in-java)
  - [Generics - Cannot add to a List with unbounded wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637125/generics-cannot-add-to-a-list-with-unbounded-wildcard)
  - [What is the difference betwen Collection<?> and Collection<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777701/what-is-the-difference-betwen-collection-and-collectiont)

-- edit --

For the picky guys who would want to know why am I doing such stupid things. If you don't care why am I doing this, don't bother the rest.

Why?

I'm writing several implementations (e.g. Quick, Insertion, Heap, Mixed, Intro, Bubble, ...) of following interface:

```
package com.kash.src;

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Interface that provides all sorting functions for all possible representations of a list of Objects (non-primitive
 * types). <br>
 * - {@link List}<{@link Comparable}><br>
 * - Array of < ? extends {@link Comparable}><br>
 * - {@link List}< ? > with external {@link Comparator}<br>
 * - Array of < ? > with external {@link Comparator}<br>
 * 
 * @author Kashyap Bhatt
 * 
 */

public interface Sorter {
    <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(List<T> list);

    <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(T[] array);

    <T extends Object> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c);

    <T extends Object> void sort(T[] array, Comparator<? super T> c);
}
```

So that I can test all my sort implementations and test them. I wanna compare the results with Java's sort implementations, so I'm also writing an implementation of this interface which internally just calls Java's sort methods. That's where I faced the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Collections.sort()` does not sort arrays, but `List`s.

Comment: Thanks. Stupid me. :) I was supposed to call Arrays.sort() in this wrapper.

Answer (score 3):

[Collections#sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) expects a `List` while you are passing an array.
Do:

```
public static <T> void sort1(T[] array, Comparator<? extends T> c) {
        Collections.sort(Arrays.asList(array), c); // line 11
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Stupid me. :) I was supposed to call Arrays.sort() in this wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

> The method `sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>)` in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments `(T[], Comparator<capture#1-of ? extends T>)` Main.java   /Sorting/src/com/kash/test  line 11

You are passing `T[]` where `List<T>` is expected and `Comparator<? extends T>` where `Comparator<? super T>` is expected.

**Why do you think it should not give error?**